# Can I write all "append" code in a row using "if"?

Tags: python, if-statement, append

how can I in python append by condition, can i write like this?

```py
'Segment 2': result['trips'][0]['segments'][2]['bookingClass']) if(len(result['trips'][0]['segments'] == 2,
```

at the moment i try to write all in one row, is this possible?

```py
response.append({'Fare Type': result['fareType'], 'Segment 2': result['trips'][0]['segments'][2]['bookingClass']) if(len(result['trips'][0]['segments'] == 2})
```

Comment: Give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can (using a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)):

```py
response.append({'Fare Type': result['fareType'],'Segment 2': result['trips'][0]['segments'][2]['bookingClass']}) if(len(result['trips'][0]['segments'] == 2)) else None
```

But probably shouldn't, as this way has a useless `else` statement at the end, and is difficult to read. The code will be much simpler with an `if` statement:

```py
if len(result['trips'][0]['segments']) == 2:
    response.append({
        'Fare Type': result['fareType'],
        'Segment 2': result['trips'][0]['segments'][2]['bookingClass']
    })
```